# How to group with condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a table with customer_ID and date_reward and I'm looking to get a group count of reward(s) sent by customer_ID with a condition that each group will only have rewards sent out with a 60 day gap. If the difference between two dates for a customer_ID is greater than 60 then it should be a separate group for that same customer_ID.

For example,

```
customer_ID  date_reward
CD3859          3/3/2017
CD3859          4/3/2017
CD3859          7/14/2017
CD3859          8/2/2017
CD1190          1/2/2017
CD1190          2/28/2017
CD1190          3/15/2017
CD4457          5/5/2017
CD4457          6/15/2017
CD4457          7/2/2017
CD4457          9/30/2017
CD4457          10/30/2017
CD4457          1/15/2018
CD4457          4/7/2018
```

The output could have multiple lines for the same customer_ID if the dates are more than 60 days apart.

Expected output:

```
customer_ID group_count
CD3859          2
CD3859          2
CD1190          3
CD4457          3
CD4457          2
CD4457          1
CD4457          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr solution. It results in different order of customer_ID, I think b/c `dplyr` sorts groups by default, wasn't sure if that was worth re-sorting at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date_reward = as.Date(date_reward, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(customer_ID) %>%
  arrange(date_reward) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(date_reward - lag(date_reward, default = 0) >= 60)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(customer_ID, grp)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  customer_ID   grp     n
  <chr>       <int> <int>
1 CD1190          1     3
2 CD3859          1     2
3 CD3859          2     2
4 CD4457          1     3
5 CD4457          2     2
6 CD4457          3     1
7 CD4457          4     1
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. The solution you proposed worked for me.